# Possible to pass an enum type name as an argument in Swift?

Tags: swift, types, enums

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to pass around enum's type in the same way that you can pass `Class` objects in Swift.

My actual use case is a bit more complicated than this, but for discussion, let's say I have two `Int` enums:

```
enum Foo: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
    case firstFoo = 0
    case anotherFoo = 1
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .firstFoo:
            return "Hello Foo"
        case .anotherFoo:
            return "Goodbye Foo"
        }
    }
}

enum Bar: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
    case firstBar = 0
    case anotherBar = 1
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case . firstBar:
            return "Hello Bar"
        case . anotherBar:
            return "Goodbye Bar"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to write a function like this:

```
func justAnExample(whichEnum: enum) {
    let val = whichEnum(rawValue: 0)
    print("description: \(String(val))")
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
justAnExample(Foo)
// prints: "description: Hello Foo"
justAnExample(Bar)
// prints: "description: Hello Bar"
```

Is this possible?  If so, what is the signature of `whichEnum` in the function declaration?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that enums with raw values automatically conform to the [`RawRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rawrepresentable) protocol. You can define a generic function that takes a metatype argument of a given type `T` (spelled as `T.Type`), where that `T` is [`RawRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rawrepresentable) and, also in your case, its [`RawValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rawrepresentable/1540809-rawvalue) is `Int`.

This will allow you to pass in the metatypes of both `Foo` and `Bar`, spelled `Foo.self` and `Bar.self` respectively:

```
func justAnExample<T : RawRepresentable>(_ enumType: T.Type) where T.RawValue == Int {

  // Note that an explicit use of init is required when creating an instance from a
  // metatype. We're also using a guard, as `init?(rawValue:)` is failable.
  guard let val = enumType.init(rawValue: 0) else { return }
  print("description: \(val)")
}

justAnExample(Foo.self) // prints: "description: Hello Foo"
justAnExample(Bar.self) // prints: "description: Hello Bar"
```

Comment: How do I write this in swift 4, where the method also returns a value? With "where T.RawValue == Int -> String" it thinks the RawValue is (Int)->String EDIT: The method return type comes BEFORE the where clause!

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to write extension for RawRepresentable, E.G.

```
extension RawRepresentable where RawValue == Int{

    static func testPrint() {
        print(Self(rawValue: 0))
    }
}
enum Thing: Int {
    case Test = 0
}
// prints "Optional(Thing.Test)"
Thing.testPrint()
```

Then you don't have to worry about passing anything. And of course it will work for more than just enums

Comment: This doesn't help, because I don't have `Thing`.  I'm trying to pass `ThingA` or `ThingB` as an argument,

Comment: If it's ThingA: Int and ThingB: Int it should be fine. You could also write an extension for any other RawValue type

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem though. I want to call `someOtherMethod(Thing)`, not `Thing.testPrint()`