# Passing various enum case as function param in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, enums, parameters, func

I have two simple enums like this:

```
    enum Bar:String {
        case obj1 = "Object1"
    }

    enum Foo:String {
        case obj2 = "Object2"
    }
```

I want to write a function that takes enum case as param and it should print the case raw value. Something like this:

```
printCase(Bar.obj1) // prints "Object1"
printCase(Foo.obj2) // prints "Object2"
```

I tried like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793536/possible-to-pass-an-enum-type-name-as-an-argument-in-swift) but it takes the whole enum as param. But my case is different from it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked question is actually quite close - you just have to change the parameter type to just `T`, instead of `T.Type`:

```
func printCase<T : RawRepresentable>(_ e: T) where T.RawValue == String {
    print(e.rawValue)
}
```

Since you are accepting an instance of the enum, not the enum type itself.

Of course, you don't have to restrict this to enums `where T.RawValue == String`, since `print` can print `Any`thing.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define a generic function that takes a `RawRepresentable` and returns its `rawValue` property.

```
func rawValue<T: RawRepresentable>(of case: T) -> T.RawValue {
    `case`.rawValue
}

rawValue(of: Foo.obj2) // "Object2"
rawValue(of: Bar.obj1) // "Object1"
```

Comment: Although this fits OP's expectations of what an answer should look like, it's a layer of needless indirection. Better to just `Foo.obj2.rawValue` directly

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I agree for such a simple example. However, OP might have a more complex requirement which might justify the generic function.